# WMS orthophotos not visible on screen

Tags: qgis, wms

Using QGIS on Windows XP based desktop. I have been loading orthophotos from a WMS server up to yesterday morning. Today QGIS correctly connects to the server and apparently loads some bytes, however I only get overlapping yellow frames and the codes of the orthophotos on a white screen.

No error messages appear.

What I have done up to now: I rebooted the pc, I checked the WMS URL (even if QGIS connects to the server), I have installed the latest version of QGIS (now 2.0.1). Any clue? I can correctly view images and videos on my PC.

Comment: I have some problems using JPEG in WMS in QGIS, but PNG works fine. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found that by removing the wms layer of the ortophotos from the drop-down menu and then adding it again (same URL but renamed differently), then the ortophotos are loaded and visible on screen. Apparently this doesn't solve the problem permanently because I have to do this everytime I restart a new session (but at least it let me work).

Comment: Very hard to analyze this further without being able to test that WMS. Is is open for all?